# Restart only sidecar container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have two containers in my POD. First container is my main application and second is used as sidecar container having following images having following Dockerfile.

```
FROM scratch

EXPOSE 8080
ADD my-binary /

ENV GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-binary"]
```

Basically it's using **scratch** and my-binary is a go application which running as process. So I cannot **exec** on this side car container. I have a requirement to re-start the side container(my-binary), but there should be no change in the main container. Main container should not be altered in any way.

Is there any possibility, how I can achieve this?

Thank you so much for looking into this.

Someone has asked to provide the complete details of POD, then you can consider following pod structure

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-deploy
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: my-main-app-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      - name: my-go-binary
        image: my-go-binary-image
```

Please note-

```
kubectl exec POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME reboot
```

this is not going to work for 2nd container as it is scratch image.

Comment: Please provide more details. also provide your pod.yaml.

Comment: I am not sure why entire POD structure is important here, but I just provided a sample in case to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

So, your `reboot` command wasn't working (of course it will newer work) cause of using `scatch` as the base image.

> This image is most useful in the context of building base images (such as [debian](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/debian/) and [busybox](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/busybox/)) or super minimal images (that contain only a single binary and whatever it requires, such as hello-world).

See, https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

> The base image `scratch` is Docker's reserved minimal image. It can be a starting point for building small-sized containers. Using the `scratch` “image” signals to the build process that you want the next command in the Dockerfile to be the first filesystem layer in your image.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch

From you provided dockerfile, there is the only filesystem is your go-binery. There is nothing other than this. That's why you can't (couldn't) run `reboot` command. If you change the base image like `busybox` or `alpine` or anything other you will be able to run the `reboot` command.

> But keep in mind that your new base image must have a proper shell to run your expected command. For example, the `busybox` image has shell (`bash`) and so it's possible to run `reboot` command. And the `alpine` image has shell (`sh`) too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot change scratch image to any other base image like alpine etc.

Comment: Reference link you provided https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch is not valid

Comment: Sorry for the invalid link. fixed the invalid link.